# set font face in webview from asset folder

Tags: android, fonts, android-fonts

Hi all in my application I amusing webview, In this webview I want to set font type programatically. Currently in my asset folder I have Roboto-Bold.ttf, Roboto-Light.ttf,..... and some other file. Currently I am setting it as:

```
text = "<html><head>"
                + "<style type=\"text/css\">body{color: #000; text-align: justify; background-color: #fff;font-family: file:///android_asset/fonts/Roboto-Medium;}"
                + "</style></head>"
                + "<body>"
                + sb.toString()
                + "</body></html>";
```

But i think it is not working, because it generates same output as for:

```
text = "<html><head>"
                + "<style type=\"text/css\">body{color: #000; text-align: justify; background-color: #fff;font-family: \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}"
                + "</style></head>"
                + "<body>"
                + sb.toString()
                + "</body></html>";
```

Here I am using font-familyas: font-family: \"Helvetica Neue but still both produces same output.

Then how I can set font type Roboto-Light.ttf which  is present in my assets/fonts folder.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried setting the font to the view instead of the text?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
text = "<html><head>"

            + "<style type=\"text/css\"> @font-face { font-family:'HelveticaNeue'; src: url('file:///android_asset/HelveticaNeue.TTF');}body{color: #000; text-align: justify; background-color: #fff;font-family: \"HelveticaNeue\";}"

            + "</style></head>"

            + "<body>"

            + sb.toString()

            + "</body></html>";
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but still not working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must extends your one `webview`, create new `WebViewClient` and then Override `shouldInterceptRequest` and look for any font request, something like this:

```
text = "<html><head>"

        + "<style type=\"text/css\"> @font-face { font-family:'Roboto'; src: url('Roboto-Light.ttf') format('truetype');}body{color: #000; text-align: justify; background-color: #fff;font-family: \"Roboto\";}"

        + "</style></head>"

        + "<body>"

        + sb.toString()

        + "</body></html>";
```

android the WebView class should look like:

```
public class Temp extends WebView
{
    Context mContext;

    public Temp(Context context)
    {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public Temp(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        setWebViewClient(createWebViewClient());
        setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    }

    protected WebViewClient createWebViewClient()
    {
        return new WebViewClient()
        {
            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url)
            {
                if(url.contains("Roboto-Light.ttf"))
                {
                    return getFontFromAsset("Roboto-Light.ttf", "application/x-font-ttf");
                }
                else
                {
                    return null; // let the webview handle request
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private WebResourceResponse getFontFromAsset(String fontName, String mimeType)
    {
        InputStream fontIn = null;
        try
        {
            fontIn = mContext.getAssets().open(fontName);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(fontIn == null)
            return null;
        else
        {
            WebResourceResponse response = new WebResourceResponse(mimeType, "UTF-8", fontIn);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```